# Calculate slice means for several objects within a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

For a current project, I am planning to calculate the mean values for a number of objects/columns in a Pandas DataFrame.

With the current script, the mean calculations work well for the first column `rating_recommend`, leading to the following outcome:

```
stock_symbol  quarter   rating_recommend
A             2008Q2    1.123            
A             2008Q3    1.321 
A             2008Q4    1.674 
A             2009Q1    1.003
A             2009Q2    1.245 
A             2009Q3    1.177
```

The code however ignores the subsequent columns `rating_outlook` and `rating_ceo`, which are also included in the underlying DataFrame. Goal is to get an output with the following format:

```
stock_symbol  quarter   rating_recommend rating_outlook  rating_ceo
A             2008Q2    1.123            2.123.          1.345
A             2008Q3    1.321            1.765           1.784
A             2008Q4    1.674            2.009           1.246
A             2009Q1    1.003            1.865           1.987
A             2009Q2    1.245            1.567           1.765
A             2009Q3    1.177            1.987           1.567
```

Is there any smart tweak to make this happen? The corresponding section of the script looks as follows:

```
# Datetime conversion
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['quarter'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('Q')

# Definition of the data objects
def get_top_n_bigram(row):
    # Convert quantitative data and remove null values
    df['rating_recommend'] = pd.to_numeric(df['rating_recommend'], errors='coerce')
    df['rating_outlook'] = pd.to_numeric(df['rating_outlook'], errors='coerce')
    df['rating_ceo'] = pd.to_numeric(df['rating_ceo'], errors='coerce')

    return df['rating_recommend', 'rating_outlook', 'rating_ceo'].mean()

# Grouping data and assigning this as a new dataframe
newdf = df.groupby(['stock_symbol', 'quarter']).mean()

# Exporting the dataframe to Excel
newdf.to_excel('total_bigrams_pro.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html?highlight=filter#applying-multiple-functions-at-once):

```
df['rating_recommend'] = pd.to_numeric(df['rating_recommend'], errors='coerce')
df['rating_outlook'] = pd.to_numeric(df['rating_outlook'], errors='coerce')
df['rating_ceo'] = pd.to_numeric(df['rating_ceo'], errors='coerce')

df = (df
      .groupby(['stock_symbol', 'quarter'])[['rating_recommend','rating_outlook', 'rating_ceo']].agg('mean'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the good idea. It is yielding the error `pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` thought for line `df = (df.groupby(['stock_symbol', 'quarter'])['rating_recommend','rating_outlook', 'rating_ceo'].agg('mean'))`

Comment: Many thanks - that's really weird. I am still receiving the same error message... could there be any other reason for the line not detecting the numeric types?

Comment: Make sure the columns as numeric, check if `df` object is correct and not overwritten in any other step.

Comment: Have checked all that and it seems fine. Really bizarre...

Comment: I found the solution. Still had the commands `pd.to_numeric` within the function. I have now removed this part. Again many thanks for the input and have a great weekend